# Bitcoin Transaction from MtGox hasn't shown up after several hours

Tags: mtgox, withdrawal, lost-transactions

I have withdrawn bitcoins from my account in MtGox to my Multibit installed in my computer. Several hours after BTC are not in MtGox and neither in my account. I have verified the address and it is right. I can see the direction of the address in blockchain but it appears "transactions:0". Is this normal?

Comment: If you don't see the transaction in the blockchain, then the transaction hasn't been included in a block yet, possibly because Mt Gox hasn't performed it yet. The next thing to do is to check if the transaction is pending.

Comment: I have the same issue here,
I submitted a withdrawal for 40 BTC, after 12 hours now still no record on blockchain, they steal them!!!

Comment: I have also just had a withdrawl of 13 btc from mt gox to coin base and its not showing up and its been over an hour?...any suggestions?...usually takes a week for mtgox to answer any questions

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: did you ever get your coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think MtGox usually gives you a transaction hash immediately. You can use it to track it, for example on the [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/) or [blockexplorer](https://blockexplorer.com/) websites.

Even without the transaction hash, you can still use these websites to try and find it by looking for the Bitcoin address you have withdrawn to. You may wish to check your MtGox account history to see which Bitcoin address they sent your Bitcoin.

If you do not see the transaction, don't panic. Especially if you have not included a transaction fee, miners may be slow to incorporate it into any block, in which case these websites will not find the transaction in any block, and might indeed not have seen the transaction at all.

Comment: You should still see the transaction on blockchain.info even if it is not incorporated in a block.  It should show up as "Unconfirmed".  So if you don't see it on blockchain.info after a reasonable time you should complain to MtGox